# Ansible 'when' condition not returning results from array

Tags: ansible

Facing an issue with ansible when condition. The register returns a json array list but 'when' condition won't work. Will explain what i am facing here:

First i register the directories:

```
- name: check if log dir exists
  win_stat:
    path: some\path
  register: register_some_dir
```

This is the register output:

```
"changed": false,
"register_some_dir": {
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "changed": false,
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "stat": {
                "isdir": true,
                "isarchive": false,
                "exists": true,
                "isreadonly": false,
                "creationtime": 1535985185.638003,
                "isjunction": false,
                "lastaccesstime": 1566915269.0181007,
                "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
                "nlink": 1,
                "isreg": false,
                "lastwritetime": 1566915269.0181007,
                "islnk": false,
                "attributes": "Directory",
                "path": "f:\\some\\paths",
                "filename": "logging",
                "ishidden": false,
                "isshared": false,
                "hlnk_targets": [],
                "size": 4619
            },
            "changed": false,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "item": "Folder_One",
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "failed": false,
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": "Folder_One"
        },
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "stat": {
                "isdir": true,
                "isarchive": false,
                "exists": true,
                "isreadonly": false,
                "creationtime": 1535985188.0229728,
                "isjunction": false,
                "lastaccesstime": 1568382094.0390675,
                "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
                "nlink": 1,
                "isreg": false,
                "lastwritetime": 1568382094.0390675,
                "islnk": false,
                "attributes": "Directory",
                "path": "f:\\some\\other\\paths",
                "filename": "logging",
                "ishidden": false,
                "isshared": false,
                "hlnk_targets": [],
                "size": 248191373
            },
            "changed": false,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "item": "Folder_Two",
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "failed": false,
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": "Folder_Two"
        },
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "stat": {
                "isdir": true,
                "isarchive": false,
                "exists": true,
                "isreadonly": false,
                "creationtime": 1535985191.886996,
                "isjunction": false,
                "lastaccesstime": 1566829433.7600543,
                "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
                "nlink": 1,
                "isreg": false,
                "lastwritetime": 1566829433.7600543,
                "islnk": false,
                "attributes": "Directory",
                "path": "f:\\another\\paths",
                "filename": "logging",
                "ishidden": false,
                "isshared": false,
                "hlnk_targets": [],
                "size": 0
            },
            "changed": false,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "item": "Folder_Three",
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "failed": false,
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": "Folder_Three"
        }
    ]
},
"_ansible_verbose_always": true,
"_ansible_no_log": false
```

With json filter i can filter the path like:

```
- set_fact:
    log_paths: "{{ register_some_dir | json_query('results[*].stat.path') }}"
  when: register_some_dir.results[*].stat.exists == true
```

set_fact module returns the path perfectly whithout the when condition.

But 'when' condition doesn't accept the [*] it says that it is unexpected. But it is required for an array.

if i remove the [*] from the when condition it says that 'stat' has no arrtibuut.

How can i set the when condition to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to loop through your result and test each individual element in your when condition.

Fortunately, you can do what you want by integrating the filter in a single [`jsmepath`](http://jmespath.org/) expression in your `json_query`

```
- set_fact:
    log_paths: "{{ register_some_dir | json_query('results[?stat.exists].stat.path') }}"
```